# Как вывести результат теста? (python)

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

При запуске ничего не выводит.

```
def array_search (A: list, N: int, X: int):
    #осуществляется поиск числа Х в массиве А. Число от 0 до N-1 включительно. возвращает индекс элемента Х в массиве А. Или -1 если такого нет
    return -1

def test_array_search():
    A1=[-1,2,3,4,5]
    m = array_search(A1, 5, 8)
    if m == -1:
        print("test1 -   ok" )
    else:
        print("test1 - fail")

test_array_search()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите скрипт в вопросе в рабочий вид. И у вас нет в коде запуска функции `test_array_search()`, поэтому ничего не выполнится, и соответственно не будет выведено

Comment: После исправления табуляции выводит: 'test1 -   ok'

Comment: Похоже, что после всех правок, вопрос не имеет смысла. Нужно либо вернуть первоначальную версию вопроса и добавить ответ с исправленной версией, либо удалить вовсе.